# How do I mount a network volume inside my Docker Windows container

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, docker-desktop

I need to share a network drive inside my Windows docker container under the A: drive.
The network drive I need to shared is not empty, and I would need to access it with and right permissions.
How can I achieve this? I've only found posts about people mapping their C: drive.

Should it be done during build or at runtime?

It tried the obvious

`docker run -it --rm --name windows my/image --privileged -v \\ip\mount\my\folder:A:\my\folder`

but I get this error:

```
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF6F8AFAE77: (caller: 00007FF6F8AAE4AB) Exception(2) tid(39c) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
```

I'm using Docker Desktop  2.2.0.0 on Windows 10 Pro 1903

Edit:
I should have set the image after the volumes it seems. With the following command, The error is different:

`docker run -it --rm --name windows --privileged -v \\ip\mount\my\folder:A:\my\folder my/image`

`docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '\\ip\mount\my\folder:A:my\folder'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create gMSAs for Docker container. Actually, th IT Team should do it for you (following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts), for example).
They will then provide you with a credentials file. You can then run your docker container with:

```
docker run -it --rm --name windows --security-opt "credentialspec=file://my_credentials.json" my/image
```

then, in the container, you can use `net use` to mount your volume under the  letter you want.
You can't do it in the container run command, however.